# How to install JRE on firefox with fedora (64bits)

Tags: java, firefox, 64bit

What do I need to run Java web applications on firefox with my 64bits fedora 17?
I can't pass [this test](http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp) but I have installed the x64 rpm [from there](http://www.java.com/fr/download/linux_manual.jsp). What is missing?

Additional note: I tried to follow [these instructions](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=258850) (linking the libnpjp2.so) but then the JRE test crashed firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [this page](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/java-for-opensuse), I got the solution.

Using the JRE x64 rpm mentioned in the question, without icedtea plugin, all you need to do is linking the JRE library to firefox this way :

```
ln -s /usr/java/jre1.7.0_05/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so ~/.mozilla/plugins/
```

In fact I just copied it the first time this is why it crashed. After that you can verify the plugin is installed in firefox by typing in the url :

```
about:plugins
```

And Java(TM) Plug-in 1.x will show up, no need to restart firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use icedtea plugin.
You installed java on your system, but you probably don't have the needed plugin in firefox.
In arch that plugin is icedtea, and as i can see, it also is in fedora:
http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/IcedTea

Comment: Just installed Icedtea and I get an error with the app I tried (gaikai). It says I am running an unsupported version and I need the official one, maybe there is another way ?

Comment: Got it working now, I am adding the answer